# Make child window always on top of all windows

Tags: wpf, window, viewmodel

I'm writing in wpf. In my viewModel I have a command that opens new window. However sometimes this child window is placed under the parent window.  (if for instance I work in my application, then open browser and want to return to my application). Window is opened as follows:

```
MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel(oper);
Mywindow window = new MyWindow();
//Initialize viewModel and set window.DataContext to this viewModel
CWPFWindowWithViewModelHelper<IWindowWithViewModel>.InitializeViewModel(window, vm);
window.ShowDialog();
```

I want this child window to be always visible when opened. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
window.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: It will be applied for all windows in system and not just for parent.

Comment: Certainly not "all windows in system"... it will be applied to the window on which you set the property, and perhaps on its child windows. Did you try it ?

Comment: Ah, ok I see what you mean now. Do you want the window to be modal ? (i.e. disable the parent window until it's closed)

Comment: what I mean, when I set window.TopMost=true to my child window, it will be always on top (e.g. even if I open other windows like browser etc). And yes I want it to be modal

Comment: I want to set window.Owner=this but this is my ViewModel and it doesn't know anything about parent window.

Answer (score 12):

just try with

```
window.Owner=this
```

Comment: but how can I do this in my ViewModel? Please remember that I am creating new child window in my ViewModel so "this" will reference to currentViewModel

Comment: Since it is a ViewModel and not a Model, I would have assumed it had a reference to the parent View (i.e. Window).

Comment: Be sure to review "Owned Windows" at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx)