# how to make popup windows always on top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I want to have a javascript/jQuery popup window (child page) that is always in front of the parent page, something like facebook's current picture viewing feature.

it would be closed by the user clicking on the close button.

I have tried as below:

```
mywindow  = window.open ("DownloadForm.aspx", "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=350,height=150");
mywindow.moveTo(350, 350);
```

this code successfully opened a child page in front of the parent page, but there is jQuery code ( $(#test).click() ) on the parent page which causes the parent page to always be in front.

I tried putting the `window.open()` code after `$(#test).click()`, but it didn't solve the problem.

The `$(#test).click()` is necessary, therefore I need to have a workaround.

I appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838944/make-child-window-always-on-top-of-parent-window)

Comment: If it's okay for the popup to open "inside" the parent page, you could try out a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) with `{modal: true}` - this will open a pseudo-subwindow and grey out the original page, keeping the dialog "on top" until it closes.  Try Googling [jquery lightbox](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=jquery+lightbox), too - I think those would apply here as well, though I've never used them myself...  Good luck!

Comment: I thought the point of SO was to both answer questions and educate users and developers. Popup windows are so 90s. They should be replaced by lightboxes or by modal windows. Modern browsers support modal windows, created either by CSS or jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

```
myWindow.focus()
```

Many modern browsers prevent this from working, but it's the only way.

Answer (score 2):

use following javascript code in the page you are opening in popup

```
<body onblur="self.focus();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you cannot control the order of the window. Instead of a popup (which is often and usually blocked by browsers) why not investigate using a lightbox javascript plugin. They are usually free, stylish and work well.

Comment: and this is what facebook is doing

Comment: Facebook uses there own library of Javascript API and modal boxes. Simply Google 'lightbox javascript' or 'javascript modal dialog' and you will find many downloadable scripts. Choose one taht fits waht you need.

Comment: Yes, I mean Facebook is not using a popup window there a using a popup layer in the same page.

Comment: Yes, facebook just has absolute positioned div's with a higher z-index (its a css style)

Answer (score 0):

Just set it from the modal css. The `z-index` is normally set to 1. Just change it to 9999. That is the purpose of the `z-index`, to set the popup top level.

If not using bootstrap popup, then you need to use css to set it. Browsers are not guaranteed to place nice with `.focus()` on a window.