# How can I stop resizing or lock the window size or freeze the window size in eel python library

Tags: javascript, python, desktop-application, eel

coders

Currently, I am working on a Python project where I have to make a desktop application using the python EEL library and I have done half of the project.

Recently I found out that I need to freeze my window size. So is there any option or trick so I can freeze my window size or in javascript to stop the user from resizing my window?

What argument could be added to these options?

```
import eel
    app_options = {
        'mode': "chrome",
        'host': "localhost",
        'port': 0
    } #'mode' as 'chrome-app' also has same issue
    eel.init('web')
    eel.start('main.html', size=(600,600), options=app_options)
```

Any type of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`eel` is a gate through python and javascript in the browser. since javascript can not prevent the user from controlling browser window size, so you can not do that by `eel`.

and I think the following link may help you to go around https://stackoverflow.com/a/55943053/8286874